# Linq expressions syntax and Compile

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I was looking up an example how to use a particular part of the Telerik grid framework (ASP.NET MVC3, but that's not really relevant here). They have a chunk of code which takes a list of filter descriptions and builds an expression:

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<MyModel, bool> exp = 
               ExpressionBuilder.Expression<MyModel>(listOfFilters);
```

Ok, so I think that's fine. The Expression wraps a lambda, which operates on MyModel to produce a bool. Great. Now, their example simply drops that into a Where like so:

```
someList = someList.Where(exp);
```

Which I am presuming should be "hey apply that expression to all the items in the list (which is of course generic MyModel too). However, VS claims that code doesn't compile. I get "No overload Where exists or System.Func has some invalid arguments".

I played around with it and find that I can compile the expression, which gives the more unseemly looking

```
someList = someList.Where(x => exp.Compile()(x));
```

Which does compile and would probably work, but it makes me uncomfortable because I'm now clearly operating outside what I know.

Is there some reason why (IDE setting, flag, stale documentation) the example's approach doesn't work? 
Is there a rough equivalency to my hack and the example?
Should I structure that hack differently to avoid some hideous problem (like, its not going to compile the expression each and every time it checks an item in the list, right? I think it's smart enough for that?)

-- Edit
Yes it was IEnumerable. I fell into the "all Wheres are created equal" trap.
Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just doing

```
someList = someList.Where(exp.Compile());
```

If someList is an `IEnumerable` you will need to use `exp.Compile()` which returns a `Func<MyModel,bool>`

If someList is an `IQueryable` you can use `exp.Compile()` or you can use `exp` which is an `Expression<Func<MyModel, bool>>`

Comment: Interesting. That also works, so I can clean up my code a little. I guess then the question is why do I need to do that at all?

Comment: This is correct. A side note: This has horrible performance because compiling an expression is very expensive.

Comment: @Mikeb IEnumerable<T>.Where() takes a Func, not an expression, right?  Your Expression.Compile is producing a Func - that's probably why it works.  Given the usage in the Telerik example though, I would see if the Telerik framework has an extension method Where somewhere that takes an Expression.

Comment: If one has an IQueryable is the performance issue of the compile still there? (ie, is IQueryable just hiding the same step behind a green curtain?)

Comment: @usr: Not really. You've got to put it in context. As long as you only compile the function once, you're fine...

Comment: This is universally true. Doing almost anything once in software is cheap. The above example sure doesn't look like it. Just warning....

Answer (score 4):

There are two versions of the `Where()` method: one operates on `IEnumerable<T>` and takes `Func<T, bool>`, the other works on `IQueryable<T>` and takes `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`. The reason for that is that `IQueryable<T>` can represent some remote data, like a database table. And when you query the table, you don't want to transmit the whole table just to find the single item you're looking for.

That's the reason why there is an `Expression`: it's used to represent some code, but in a way that can be easily processed, and for example converted to SQL. Or you can compile it to normal IL code and make a delegate out of it.

If you want to operate on a normal in-memory list (that implements `IEnumerable<T>`, but not `IQueryable<T>`), you don't need expressions at all, you can work with delegates all the time and your code will be probably simpler and faster.

But if you want to work with `Expression`s, you can, as you discovered. There are several options:

1. Use [the `AsQueryable()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb507003.aspx). This way, you will get methods like `Where()` that work with `Expression`s.

   ```
   someList.AsQueryable().Where(exp)
   ```
2. Compile the expression by calling [the `Compile()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362.aspx). It returns a delegate that you can pass directly to `Where()`.

   ```
   someList.Where(exp.Compile())
   ```

Your attempt actually will compile the expression for each item in the collection, so it will probably have bad performance.

Answer (score 2):

What is the type of someList?  I assume `List<T>`.  There is no extension method `Where` that allows an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` on `List<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` for that matter.

You are probably used to sending expressions to a queryable.  `IQueryable<T>` does have a `Where` extension method that allows `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`.  To access it you would have to do the following

```
var someQueryable = someList.AsQueryable().Where(exp);
```

That return type will by `IQueryable<T>`.  To put that back in someList, you will need to add an `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()` depending on the type of someList.

This may not be the best way to do it, but it lets you use `exp` as you expected.

Comment: @ScottW that does not allow an expression.  It allows a `Func<T, bool>`.

Comment: oh my mistake, didn't notice the expression part.

Comment: I edited my response to put the type in code instead of just the word expression.